# CSS tabs overlapping

Tags: tabs, positioning, z-index, css

the following HTML code has a sample used from example 6 given on http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tabview { min-height: 250px; position: relative; width: 100%; }
        .tabview > div { display: inline; }
        .tabview > div > a { margin-left: -1px; position: relative; left: 1px; text-decoration: none; color: black; background: white; display: block; float: left; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid white; }
        .tabview > div:not(:target) > a { border-bottom: 0; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #eee); }   
        .tabview > div:target > a { background: white; }    
        .tabview > div > div { background: white; z-index: -2; left: 0; top: 30px; bottom: 0; right: 0; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }    
        .tabview > div:not(:target) > div { position: absolute }
        .tabview > div:target > div { position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabview">
        <div id="tab1">
            <a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
            <div>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">
            <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
            <div>2. One might well argue, that...</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3">
            <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
            <div>3. One might well argue, that...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is, when there's lot of text in any tab, it's end part is not hidden when you switch to another tab.

For example, in the code given above - the end contents of Tab1 can be seen even when you switch to other tabs.

In another worse case, if more tabs have lot of text - then the contents overlap.

How can this be solved?

One way to solve this is to increase min-height in the tabview class.
But in my application the tab contents are generated in real-time (from some web service), and I don't have idea about their size.

Note: The code works only in non-IE browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
.tabview > div > div
{
overflow: auto;
}
```

Solves both the problems. The end text is no longer visible and even with a lot of content, it does not overlap.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRZDA/2/)

Comment: Why would it work only in Non-IE Browsers. Works on IE9 here?

Comment: Hey Jawad, adding overflow:auto adds a scrollbar on the right, which cannot be scrolled (in Firefox4) may be because of CSS properties defined earlier. Is it possible to extend the tab height depending on content size, or having max-size of all tabs as standard?

Comment: It will not work in IE8 and lower because of the selector ".tabview > div:not(:target) > div". Just use another selector which is supported in IE8 and lower. And the scrollbar will not work in FF4.0.1 beacause you have "z-index: -2". Just remove this and it will also work in FF

Comment: You just have a case of over-complicated selectors which you do not need as you cas easily acheive the same with simple selectors that are well supported by modern as well as old browsers.

Comment: got the solution by entering overflow: auto; as given in the answer and height: 100% for tabview class. Now, the parent element occupies whole screen space and child element is within parent element with scroll-bar in case of overflow.

Comment: Stupid me! height: 100%. Damn how could I miss a simple thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this on an actual website, you definitely don't want to use this pure CSS solution. Beyond the fact that it won't work properly in IE, the fact that your page moves when you switch tabs is really going to be a turnoff to your visitors.

If you were to try and make this work in IE, you'd have to rely on a Javascript solution. If you're already relying on a Javascript solution to fix the tabs, you might as well use javascript to power your tabs.

Please, check out [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). A much, much better solution.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: The current HTML page does not have any tabs, so user has to scroll to go through it. That's why, I want to provide the tab feature by making minimal changes to the code. This is the cleanest solution I found so far.

Comment: But if it's difficult to edit this, I may have to switch to solution using javascript.

Comment: Give the Tabs script a shot - it's far less additional code than you think. The only thing it does differently than what you have is that is separates the titles of the tabs from the content.